# Ruby/rails/bundler: bundling only *some* of the required gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, rpm, rhel

I need to deploy a Rails app packaged up as a RHEL RPM.  I want to bundle *some* of the gems it requires, but let the rest be satisfied from the production machine's system gems.

As an end result (for instance), I want the app to find some gems (like `versionomy`, for instance) in the app's `vendor` tree, but find the Rails `activerecord`, `actionpack`, and other gems in the host's system-wide gem library.

So far I've only found ways to bundle all-or-nothing.  Can anyone point me to documentation explaining how to use Bundler and yet have `$:` be a search path, listing the app's bundled gems first and then the system's gems?  Or if it's even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specify path for gems in vendor directory

in Gemfile:

```
gem 'versionomy', :path => 'vendor/extensions'
```

Update

Yes it will work in deployment group. 
You can specify wich gems are used in development, production and test

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'thin'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

system path for gems in my case

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/
```

check your install path by `whereis gem`

and if you are using rbenv

```
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/
```

Comment: Will that work with `bundle --deployment`?  And what's the canonical `:path` for the system gem libraries?  (Which appear to be different for Ruby 1.8.7 _versus_ 1.9, for instance.)

Comment: This looks like the closest thing to working, though it's turning out to be a right bugger to get right..  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to install the requirements you don't want to provide as their own RPMs on the building machine. Then the RPM build process will require them but not provide them.

Comment: That's not a problem; in the example, the Rails gems are already packaged as RPMs and installed on the target machine.